# How to publish a test source folder using ivy?

Tags: ivy

In my project I have two separate source folders - /src where the code is and /test for mock and test objects.

On top of the standard jar (from /src) that ivy successfully publishes for my project I would like to publish another artifact through ivy that only includes the objects in the /test folder in order to be able to share these mock objects with other projects.

Can someone please provide an ivy configuration to support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You need to build a test-jar from the test-folder, lets call it project-test.jar

```
<javac destdir="build/test" srcdir="test/">
      <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
    </javac> 
<jar destfile="dist/project-test.jar" 
        basedir="build/test"/>
```

2- Define an artifact in your ivy.xml

```
 <publications>
    <artifact name="project" type="jar"  conf="default" ext="jar"/>
    <artifact name="project-test" type="jar" conf="test  ext="jar"/>
 </publications>
```

3- Publish

```
    <ivy:resolve
        revision="${project.version}"
        conf="compile,test"
    />
    <!-- Alle Artifacts für compile mit dem jars resolver publishen -->
    <ivy:publish 
        revision="${project.version}">  
        <artifacts pattern="dist/[artifact]-[revision].[type]" />
    </ivy:publish>
```

Comment: Thank you. Where exactly are we telling it to take all the files from test-folder?

Comment: you need a javac-target and a jar-target in your build.xml to compile the test classes and put them in a new jar